# Vaadin sass -ms-filter compilation

Tags: filter, sass, vaadin

I have problem with compilation -ms-filter property in scss mixin.

mytheme.scss

```
@import "../reindeer/reindeer.scss";
@import "bg-alpha.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
  @include reindeer;

  .v-button {
    @include bg-alpha(0.7); 
    -ms-filter:alpha(opacity=0.4);      <---- OK
 }
}
```

bg-alpha.scss

```
@mixin bg-alpha ($a) {
    opacity:$a;
    -ms-filter:alpha(opacity=$a*100);    <---- ERROR
}
```

During compilation is thrown this error

```
com.vaadin.sass.internal.parser.SCSSParseException: Error when parsing file C:\Develop...\VAADIN\themes\mytheme\bg-alpha.scss
Encountered "-ms-filter" at line 3, column 9.
Was expecting one of:
"}" ...
"+" ...
">" ...
"~" ...
"[" ...
"*" ...
"&" ...
"." ...
":" ...
<INTERPOLATION> ...
"@include" ...
"@debug" ...
"@warn" ...
"@each" ...
"@if" ...
"@extend" ...
"@content" ...
<IDENT> ...
<VARIABLE> ...
<HASH> ...
"@media" ...
"@page" ...
"@font-face" ...
<KEY_FRAME_SYM> ...

at com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet.get(ScssStylesheet.java:141)
at com.vaadin.sass.internal.visitor.ImportNodeHandler.traverse(ImportNodeHandler.java:69)
at com.vaadin.sass.internal.visitor.ImportNodeHandler.traverse(ImportNodeHandler.java:81)
at com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet.importOtherFiles(ScssStylesheet.java:192)
at com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet.compile(ScssStylesheet.java:185)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveOnTheFlyCompiledScss(VaadinServlet.java:815)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN(VaadinServlet.java:601)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticResources(VaadinServlet.java:571)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:229)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This problem belongs to mixins, because when I delete "-ms-filter:alpha(opacity=$a*100);" from bg-alpha mixin, everything is ok and no error is thrown.

Please, can anybody help me solve this problem? I googled lot of hours for finding solution, but I wasnt successful. Also I tryed simulate this problem with pure sass compilator. It seems to be right sass code.

Comment: Have you tried concatenation, i. e. `-ms-filter:alpha(opacity=#{$a * 100}); `?

Comment: Thanks, but the error still completely same Encountered "-ms-filter" at line 3, column 9.

Comment: Oh... Vaadin seems to have its own SASS parser (rather than using the vanilla SASS compiler written in Ruby). You should file a bug report to Vaadin and try using the vanilla compiler.

Answer (score 0):

SASS arithmetic is a fairly new feature in Vaadin 7 - I *think* only in Vaadin 7.1 -  and appears to have a few bugs (Look at the [Vaadin Forum](http://vaadin.com/forum)); the SASS parser/compiler is not a separate library, but completely implemented in the Vaadin framework itself.

I've not used Vaadin + SASS in anger - but personally, I would

a) Ensure you're using Vaadin 7.1

b) If that doesn't work, try assigning the value to an interim variable first, e.g.

```
@mixin bg-alpha ($a) {

  $msopacity=$a * 100;

  opacity:$a;
  -ms-filter:alpha(opacity=$msopacity);    
}
```

Comment: a) Yes I'm using Vaadin 7.1

Comment: Also : you could always use SASS *outside* of Vaadin, compiling it to CSS using any of the tools available (e.g. LiveReload). See [this thread on the forum](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3167554) for more discussion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found this bug is already registered http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/11747.